# How to delete an image in Java after renaming the file and delete the original file?

Tags: java, spring, image, java-8

I got a problem when i want to update my (lets say orderNumber) and i try to renaming the file of image. lets say the original file ini MainImage15 i want to rename to MainImage16 with Files.Copy or Files.Move and after that i try to delete after succesful copying. and i got the error like this

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\User\apache\webapps\Promotion\030000\MainImage15.jpg: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

```java
public void renameFileToFileSystem(final String fileName, final String oldFileLocation, final String newFileLocation) {
    Path source = Paths.get(oldFileLocation);
    Path destination = Paths.get(newFileLocation);
    try {
        Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.delete(source);
    } catch (final IOException ioException) {
        throw new ContentManagementException(fileName, ioException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

i dont knwo what to do. should i use buffer close? but i just renaming the file . thankyou.

Comment: Not related to your problem of filelocking, but sort of an x/y problem - considering giving files unqiue (UUID?) filenames and attaching that file via a database entry. Now if you change your order number, you don't need to change any of the other records like images or anything because your database row has the same a42b-3bd3.jpg kind of filename. Bonus points it allows the image to be created before an order number (perhaps for a quote or something.)

Comment: Based on your exception, you're running this in windows?  Any virus scanners running?  You may want to exclude this directory.

Comment: yeahh. i just change the filename. no need to change the image. but why the image cannot be delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `Files.copy` keeps the file handle open.

To make sure its true - remove the line `Files.copy` and rerun - the chances are that you still won't be able to delete the file.

So you must find who keeps the handle busy. There are basically two possibilities:

1. Its somewhere else in your code
2. Its some kind of external process (antivirus, another application that you've used to render the image and so forth). You can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) that will help to find the process that keeps the handle.

Comment: its java TM binary.i dont know when i just create and instantly delete nothing happen but when i need to update orderNumber or image. i got the error message like that

Comment: So its somewhere else in your application (case 1) so you might have somewhere a code the "works" with the image - reads its pixels, applies filters - whatever. Probably that part has a bug - lack of "close" somewhere. Its hard to tell more without seeing the  code...

Comment: Wewww.. so many thanks dudeee. i solve the problem.. i follow ur instruction . i close my kaspersky. and nwo success <3. thanks so much

Comment: oh, great :) Good Luck